# disable client certificate prompt

Tags: tomcat, ssl, authentication

My application need to be enabled with SSL . I  made server.xml change in tomcat .It is working fine .now there are multiple applications hosted on the server and i want client authentication only for one apllication and for all other aplications we need server authentication but not client .
I changed clientAuth="false" in server.xml to disable client authentication . But when i send a request to server i am getting a popup with list of cerficates on browser from which i need to select one.. How can I disable certificate promping on  browser for applications where i don't need client uthentication.

Answer (score 1):

With clientAuth="false" that should only happen for resources that are marked as confidential and requiring a role, in applications that are described as requiring SSL client authentication.

Comment: If the page itself is already configured like this, it's worth checking what it embeds is too (e.g. scripts, images, ...)